# How to find geo location coordinates for a particular pixel with JPEG2000 and GML?

Tags: geolocation, jpeg2000

I have JPEG2000 image with GML in XML as metadata. From GML I can fetch location coordinates of top left pixel (0,0). Do you have any idea how to find location coordinates for any pixel in the image (m,n)?

On the image below you can see GML XML 
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution 
It can be done in python by using osgeo and gdal. That library fetches all information from xml. 
[Here](https://github.com/thebrankoo/GeoJP2Crop/blob/master/loc.py) you can check the first two lines of the function *def coord2pixel(xp, yp)* and see how to get geo info from jp2 image.